# Import IO- Using XPath to show "more" content

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, import.io

I'm totally stumped on this and reaching our for help!

I'm using Import.io crawler to extract reviews from TripAdvisor. However when I am training the crawler, the "more" button is inactive.

Here's an example of the page: [http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g295424-d306662-Reviews-Hilton_Dubai_Jumeirah_Resort-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html#REVIEWS][1]

Here is the Xpath to the review in full: //*[@id="UR288083139"]/div[2]/div/div[3]

And to the More button:
 //*[@id="review_288083139"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/p/span

Is it possible to have an Xpath so the full review is included in Import.io?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by using a Crawler then an Extractor. This would split the process into two parts.

1. Create a crawler that you'd train to capture the links for every review on the page. Make sure that you select *link* for the column.

   [Sample review from the website](http://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/ShowUserReviews-g295424-d306662-r289409027-Hilton_Dubai_Jumeirah_Resort-Dubai_Emirate_of_Dubai.html#CHECK_RATES_CONT)
2. Create an Extractor to capture the full review from the links you got from the crawler.
3. Voila! You got all reviews!

Note: If you already have all the links for the pages you need the reviews from, better make an Extractor instead of a Crawler. This way, you can chain the API to the other extractor. You'd only need a crawler if you don't know all the links.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the html is NOT on the page before you click that button, and there isn't a URL which has that data on it. So you may be out of luck.

You could try playing around with the developer console to see if you can find the full reviews buried in a xml file or dynamic URL somewhere. Im not sure how though.